# Как в foreach заменить id если изначально не известно сколько их?

Tags: php

Вывожу заголовки следующим образом:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($data as $values) {

print $title = $values[0]['title']. '<br />';
print $title = $values[1]['title']. '<br />';
print $title = $values[2]['title']. '<br />';
print $title = $values[3]['title']. '<br />';
print $title = $values[4]['title']. '<br />';
print $title = $values[5]['title']. '<br />';
print $title = $values[6]['title']. '<br />';
print $title = $values[7]['title']. '<br />';

}
```

Как правильно написать $values, чтобы не прописывать цифры, а отобразить столько, сколько есть в $data?

Спасибо!

Comment: ещё один внутренний foreach сделать

Comment: Спасибо, получилось, только в конце выполнения еще и ошибку отдает Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in `foreach($values as $val) {`

Comment: значит не везде есть values или оно null и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($data as $values) {
    if (is_array($values)) {
        foreach ($values as $title) {
            printf("%s <br />\n", $title["title"]);
        }
    }
}
```

[PHP code online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php8/d40be281b6605c0917d7503eb26fc1c4/)